# ASP .Net MVC jQuery validation does not work on form submit but works onfocusout

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, validation

This is driving me crazy. Currently working on new ASP .Net MVC project and fixing client side validation. It's not the first time I'm working with it and there are tons of questions on SO about unobtrusive validation, and I think I read them all already.

1. Form is created using `Html.BeginForm`
2. web.config `ClientValidationEnabled` and `UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled` are set to true
3. Added attributes (simple `Required` attribute) to my model `Results` property
4. All necessary scripts are included in the right order: `jquery`, `jquery.validate.js`, and then `jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js`
5. In my razor view I use

`@Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Results)
 @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Results)`

6. unobtrusive validation attributes are present in the HTML.

**Html:**

```
<textarea class="input-validation-error" cols="20" data-val="true" data-val-required="Results is required." id="Results" name="Results" rows="2"></textarea>
```

The problem is that **validation actually works but only when input value is changed, but when submit button is clicked all errors are ignored and form is posted**. So I tried to change some validator configs.

```
var settngs = $.data($('form')[0], 'validator').settings;
settngs.onsubmit = function (element) { $(element).valid(); };
```

Or something like:

```
$('form').validate({
    onsubmit: function (element) {
        this.element(element);
    }
});
```

Usually, there are problems with `onfocuout`, but not with `submit`. What can I forget or miss?

Comment: Are you including `@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Results)`?

Comment: I suggest to look up the console on your browser. If there is any error of syntax in javascript, your script may not run at all, allowing the elemento to perform the default behaviour.

Comment: is it a ajax form submit or normal form submit?

Comment: @Rudresh, it's usual form submit, I used Html.BeginForm. I don't need unobtrusive.ajax.

Comment: @FabianoAraujo, console is clear, there are no errors

Comment: @StephenMuecke, Yes, of cource, I've provided already rendered html.

Comment: _Yes of course_? You only included it 11 hours after my comment :)

Comment: @StephenMuecke, I've only updated the question... I didn't provide this code in the first time because only resulted rendered html matters and I've got already like two suggestions about using those helpers.

Comment: _because only resulted rendered html matters_ Exactly! Since your html did not include `<span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="Results" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>`, which is generated by `@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Results)`, that's why I asked :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I've finally found the issue. There was some broken custom client side validation attribute which was thrown the exception if input value was `null`. When you try to change the value of validatable input - attribute worked fine because value is `not null`, but when you submit the form with empty input it threw the **UNLOGGED by console** exception and made the post to the server. This is obviously to local, I tried to delete the question but I think it will be useful if someone ever face similar issue. ***Just keep in mind to debug your custom validation attributes on client side because exception caused by them `onsubmit` are not logged by console.***

Answer (score 0):

if you want to check control in view is valid through DataAnnotation means [Required] for property as you write in model ,then use HTML.Helper

"`@Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Property)
 @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Property)`"

this perform validation for you

not use html tags like as you write

"`<textarea>...</textarea>`"

Comment: I used `TextAreaFor` and `ValidationMessageFor`. I've provided already rendered html.

Comment: I'm saying I was using them already. I provided `<textarea>...` html to demonstrate that after render they have necessary validation attributes generated by framework. ANd still validation does not work on submit.

Answer (score 0):

use the below code and try

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        var actForm = $("#" + "FormID");
        actForm.data('validator').settings.ignore = '';

        $("#FormID").submit(function () {
            if ($("#FormID").valid() == false) {
               //error
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: That's "crutch". I want to find the source of the issue.